# Isolate variable/value from Geotiff using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to plot the values of this geotiff separately using QGIS.

Here's the geotiff:

[image]

How do I map each value separately from 0-23 (so that you get to see each land cover separately as their own data set)?

So far the best I have been able to do it isolate the datasets (by turning all unwanted variables to opacity=0 in QGIS) but that seems like a bit of a cheat, especially because I wasn't able to figure out how to make a dataset with the one variable/value I actually wanted to present.

Here is the file description of the geotiff:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 0 is your NoData value, you can use the Raster Calculator (`Raster > Raster Calculator`) with an expression like so:

```
if(km2007gh25m@1 = 1, km2007gh25m@1, 0)
```

And repeat for each land cover class value: `km2007gh25m@1 = 2` etc.

This will calculate a new raster with the original value of the land cover class (in this case 1) and everything other than that land cover as 0.

It would be time consuming to do for all 23 classes, however. Perhaps you would consider using a PyQGIS script or the Graphical Modeller to iterate through the values.

If 0 is actually one of your land cover class values, and not NoData, you can choose a value that does not appear in your original raster.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked! I really had no clue what direction to go upon solving this, cheers!