# QGIS crashes when using pyQGIS QgsRasterCalculator

Tags: raster, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff

Everytime I run the code, QGIS crashes and shows the following error report. I tried running the code line by line and it seems that the issue lied in the QgsRasterCalculator function.

Here's how the tiff file looks like in the layer panel:
[image]

as well as it's description:
[image]
[image]

the code I wrote in the python plugin in QGIS:

```
main_path = 'D:\Cons_geotiffs\\'

lyr1 = QgsRasterLayer(main_path + "lcm2007gb25m.tif")

output = main_path + "testing___.tif"

entries = []

ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras.ref = 'ras@1'
ras.layer = lyr1
ras.bandNumber = 1
entries.append(ras)

calc = QgsRasterCalculator('if(ras@1 = 1, ras@1, 0)', output, 'GTiff', \
lyr1.extent(), lyr1.width(), lyr1.height(), entries)

calc.processCalculation()
```

and the error:

```
Python Stack Trace
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Current thread 0x000064e8 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90 in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 74 in runsource
    self.runcode(code)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 251 in runsource
    return super(PythonInterpreter, self).runsource(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 228 in execCommandImpl
    res = self.runsource(src)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 442 in runFile
    self.runCommand("exec(Path('{0}').read_text())".format(filename), skipHistory=True)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_editor.py", line 329 in runScriptCode
    self.pythonconsole.shell.runFile(filename)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 660 in runScriptEditor
    self.tabEditorWidget.currentWidget().runScriptCode()


Stack Trace


QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem :
QgsMapLayer::crs :
QgsRasterCalculator::QgsRasterCalculator :
PyInit__analysis :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyObject_GC_Del :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyEval_EvalCodeEx :
PyEval_EvalCode :
PyDict_GetItemString :
PyArena_New :
PyRun_StringFlags :
PyEval_GetBuiltins :
PyEval_GetBuiltins :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyObject_GC_Del :
PyEval_EvalCodeWithName :
PyEval_EvalCodeEx :
PyEval_EvalCode :
PyEval_GetBuiltins :
PyEval_GetBuiltins :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyObject_GC_Del :
PyFloat_FromDouble :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyObject_GC_Del :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyObject_GC_Del :
PyFunction_Vectorcall :
PyFloat_FromDouble :
PyVectorcall_Call :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit__gui :
QgsCodeEditor::runCommand :
PyInit__gui :
PyArg_ParseTuple_SizeT :
PyObject_MakeTpCall :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyFloat_FromDouble :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyFloat_FromDouble :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyFunction_Vectorcall :
PyFloat_FromDouble :
PyVectorcall_Call :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
QObject::qt_static_metacall :
QAction::activate :
QAbstractButton::click :
QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QWidget::event :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main :
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :




QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.32.2-Lima
QGIS code revision: c0b8833964
Compiled against Qt: 5.15.3
Running against Qt: 5.15.3
Compiled against GDAL: 3.7.1
Running against GDAL: 3.7.1



System Info
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.19045
```

Currently, I do not understand what is the solution to the error. I might not be able to access administrative privileges on the computer I am using so I might not be able to change any whole system memory handling if that would be relevant.

In essence the end goal is to solve the problem brought up in [Isolate variable/value from Geotiff using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474039) using python programming to make it process all the values quickly (eventually via a for loop after getting it working for one value).